# Why is $\det(A - \lambda I)$ zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I was reading over some notes of mine from the Linear Algebra class I took a while ago in order to prepare myself for Computer Graphics course I'll be taking this Fall and I ran across a sentence that I can't quite grasp. It states that

> Since we have a non-zero vector $x$ in the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$, then $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$.

From reading Wikipedia page on determinants I got that

> ... the system has a unique solution exactly when the determinant is nonzero; when the determinant is zero there are either no solutions or many solutions.

So if we have vector $x$ in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$, then we have either 0 solutions or many solutions. But I still don't understand why $\det(A - \lambda I)$ has to be equal zero?

Comment: If $\det(A-\lambda I)$ was non-zero, then you could invert (via an explicit formula) $(A-\lambda I)$. Then the only solution to $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$ would be $x=(A-\lambda I)^{-1} 0 = 0$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the matrix looking like $A - \lambda I$, so don't be confused by this either. If $A$ is any square matrix and $x$ is a nonzero vector in the nullspace of $A$ then $\det(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x \ne 0$ is in the null space of $A - \lambda I$, i.e., $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$, that means that $A - \lambda I$ is singular (noninvertible), which is exactly the same as saying that its determinant is zero.

Comment: could you please explain why A has to be singular? I looked online but found no answer.

Comment: @YuriSwarovski With slightly different wording: We want $A-\lambda I$ to not be invertible because if it was, we could multiply by its inverse on both sides of the equation $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$ and obtain $x = 0$. This is trivially a solution (and would be the only one) which is not of interest, so we ask that $A-\lambda I$ not be invertible (i.e. have determinant $0$).

Comment: Yuri, have you studied eigenvectors and eigenvalues, in particular their meaning? The fact that any multiple vector of an eigenvector is an eigenvector is "synonymous" by having a non invertible matrix by the Invertible Matrix Theorem.

Comment: @imranfat As far as I understand eigenvector is just a vector in the direction of the matrix and eigenvalue is the length of that vector. So what you are saying is that since a multiple of an eigenvector is a solution to the Ax=0 and we can have infinity such solutions, the matrix has to be singular?

Comment: No. A matrix has no direction. An eigenvector $v$ is a vector whose direction is not changed under the multiplication $Av$. However, its length may change, and the factor of that change is $\lambda$. Note that $\lambda$ is not the length of an eigenvector, because its length is not fixed: given an eigenvector $v$, $\alpha v$ is also an eigenvector, for any $\alpha \ne 0$.

Comment: Note: $(A - \lambda I) x = Ax - \lambda x$. If that equals zero, then $Ax = \lambda x$, meaning that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if and only if $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$ for some $\lambda$ (that $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue) and that is true if and only if $A - \lambda I$ is singular (for some $\lambda$), which is equivalent to $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ for some (that same) $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing at all special here about $A-\lambda I$.

If $M$ is *any* square matrix with a nonzero vector in its null space, then $det(M)=0$.  Do you know that any (real) $n\times n$ matrix $M$ induces a linear map from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$?  Matrix $M$ is non-singular if and only if the induced map is one-to-one.  But if $x$ is a nonzero vector in the null space of $M$, this is violated since $M$ also sends the zero vector to itself.  Thus $M$ is singular in the case you are considering.

Comment: so because the matrix is no longer an injection i.e. there are two solutions for each input, the determinant cannot be non-zero?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of it this way helped me to grasp the idea.

$(A-\lambda I)x = Bx = 0$

A homogeneous systems of linear equations  $Bx=0$ has non zero solutions only if it has dependent rows (equations). If a matrix has dependent rows its determinant is zero.

wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations